# Compare 2 timestamps in PHP and get the days between?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have 2 timestamps (like 3434368673) an want to get the days between them. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

```
$days = unixtojd($t1) - unixtojd($t2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$days = (int) ( abs($timestampA - $timestampB) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
```

Comment: This returns me 415000 days for example ... it needs more brackets, but its working. It has to be (60 * 60 *24).