# PHP difference date to day

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date Difference in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php)
>   [Compare 2 timestamps in PHP and get the days between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987506/compare-2-timestamps-in-php-and-get-the-days-between)

I've 2 dates like `15/02/2012` and `18/03/2012`, I need to know the number of days difference between them. Does such a utility exist in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`date_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$diff = (int) ( abs(strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2)) / (60 * 60 * 24) );
echo 'diff:' . $diff
```

Comment: I would recommend against using `strtotime` in favour of [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime).

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

*Example*

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

*Output*

```
+2 days
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn those dates into timestamps:

```
$ts1 = strtotime("15-02-2012");
$ts2 = strtotime("18-03-2012");
$diff = ($ts2 - $ts1)/86400;

echo $diff . " days";
```